# rounding off values to 2 decimal places in java

Tags: java-7

I am using Java 7 and I just want to round off values to 2 decimal places, sample code is also given from various stackoverflow links :

```
Double d1= 4.37  ,      d2=0.694444444; //expected result after multiplication of numbers d1 and d2 is 3.04
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#####");
       String str = df.format(d1*d2);
        d=(Double)df.parse(str);
        System.out.println(d);//Prints 3.03472
        df = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
        str = df.format(d);
        d= (Double)df.parse(str);
        System.out.println(d);//Prints 3.0347
       df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
        str = df.format(d);
        d= (Double)df.parse(str);
        System.out.println(d);//Prints 3.035
       df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        str = df.format(d);
        d= (Double)df.parse(str);
        System.out.println(d); //Prints my desired result 3.04
```

Is it not possible to possible to do this in 2 or 3 statements.

Regards

Kris

Comment: lol, it's java. most things take at least 10 lines of code

Comment: Why not leave the decimal resolution as is, and us `System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", d))` when you want to output.

Comment: @HaleemurAli : I want to assign my final result 3.04 to a double variable finally to store it in database. Regards, Kris

Comment: @chiku but the answer to 2dp is actually 3.03, not 3.04. You are incorrectly getting 3.04 because you are rounding the intermediate results of rounding. I would simply do `System.out.printf("%.2f%n", d);`

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou: by rounding of in the intermediate steps upto 10 iterations I am accurate answer. Regards, kris

Comment: Now it's working, just check the updated code....

Comment: @chiku no, if you mark the value 3.0347 on a scale, you will find that it is closer to 3.03 than to 3.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the expected result 3.04 makes no sense, if you round to the closest value it should be 3.03. The result of 4.37*0.694444444 is 3.03472222028 and that is closer to 3.03 then to 3.04:

```
abs 3.03472222028 - 3.03 =  0.00472222028
abs 3.03472222028 - 3.04 =  0.00527777972
```

So actually all you  need is

```
new DecimalFormat("#.##");
```

But as Klitos says, you would probably want to keep the real value as long as possible, and only round if you have to persist it to the database. Where you could use

```
String.format("%.2f", value)
```

**Update 17/11**

With the example you provided:

```
  DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
  String result = df.format(10.85*1/1.44);
```

The result is **7.53** (correct).
However, with your code, the result is **7.54**, which is wrong.

That is because you round every digit sequentially and the errors accumulate, resulting in a rounding error, as can be seen in the example you provided.

So you really don't need to write your own rounding algorithm.You can just use the default from `new DecimalFormat("#.##")`.

Comment: I am writing a small java program to extract excel round-off values and dump into db, the sample data is as shown : 

Revenue,          Fx Rate(1/1.44),       Actual,       Calc,           Diff                 ,                         (Revenue * Fx Rate)
10.85 ,              0.694444444 ,            7.53 ,      7.54 ,         -0.009999999999999787 ,           7.5347222174     //WRONG
10.98 ,              0.694444444 ,            7.63 ,      7.63 ,                  0.0                   ,                    7.62499999512    // ACCURATE
Regards, kris